# Running a system command (pdflatex) within my Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, io, pdflatex

So I have a Rails application that upon user submission should generate some kind of a .tex file based on the user input, compile it into a pdf, and deliver the pdf. Through process of elimination, I am pretty positive that everything is working except for one line; the one where pdflatex is called.

Here's the vital snippet of code:
(If it matters, its located in the Questions controller under the generate action, which is called after the form sends the relevant information. Though this may not be the best way, I'm pretty certain its not the cause of the error)

```
texHeader = 'app\assets\tex\QuestionsFront.txt' 
texOut = 'app\assets\tex\Questions.tex'

#copy latex header to new file
FileUtils.cp(texHeader, texOut)

File.open(texOut, 'a+') do |fout|
      fout.write("\n")
         # a loop writes some more code to fout (its quite lengthy)
      fout.write("\\end{enumerate}\n")
      fout.write("\\end{document}")
      #The problem line:
      puts `pdflatex app/assets/tex/Questions.tex --output-directory=app/assets/tex`
    end

    filename = 'Questions.pdf'
    filelocation = "app\\assets\\tex\\" + filename

    File.open(filelocation, 'r') do |file|
      send_file file, :filename => filename, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"
    end
end
```

Here's my reasoning: It generates the .tex file correctly, and given a pre-created Questions.pdf file it sends it just fine.  When the command in the puts is copied to the terminal, it runs without a hitch (the file begins with \nonstopmode so no worries about small errors).  But for some reason, when I run the above script, not even a log file is created with an error.

What am I overlooking? Any ideas? Any way of seeing what output the puts line is creating?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my own problem. The error is pretty interesting. You'll see I'm calling

```
 puts `pdflatex app/assets/tex/Questions.tex --output-directory=app/assets/tex`
```

within the block

```
File.open(texOut, 'a+') do |fout|
```

where just a few lines prior

```
texOut = 'app\assets\tex\Questions.tex'
```

**Basically, I'm trying to get latex to compile a document *while the file is still open*.** So long as I'm in the File.open block, the file is open, and its automatically closed upon the end of the block.
Cutting and pasting the line of code down below the end of the block made it work just like I wanted. However, for the sake of clarity and the rare case where someone else has this problem, its actually better to open a separate system shell, navigate to the directory where the latex document is and do the compiling there. So, my updated code looks  like:

```
  fout.write("\\end{document}")
end

system 'runlatex.bat'
```

where that batch file is as follows:

```
cd app/assets/tex
pdflatex Questions.tex
```

That way any additional files in the tex directory are found, the log file is created there, etc.

Reason why I never got a log file? The pdflatex never executed - the OS stopped it with a permissions error before it ever ran.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Backticks (and `%x{}`) provide the same parsing context as a double quoted string. That means that the usual backslashed escape sequences are interpreted inside backticks; in particular, `\t` is a tab so this:

```
puts `pdflatex app\assets\tex\Questions.tex --output-directory=app\assets\tex`
```

will end up with two tabs in and that breaks everything. You can start escaping your backslashes (I think you'll need two or three backslashes to get one down to the shell) or switch to normal slashes (which Windows usually accepts in paths):

```
puts `pdflatex app/assets/tex/Questions.tex --output-directory=app/assets/tex`
```

Alternatively, you could switch to [`open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) to avoid the escaping and quoting issues and also get better error handling capabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I always mix up my slashes. I changed the line of code, but I still get nothing. No log file, no output. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @ngmiceli: Does `pdflatex` print anything useful on the standard output or will it write it all to `--output-directory`?

Comment: It prints a ton of stuff to standard output, but usually the same _exact_ content is usually printed to a log file as well.  I admit, I don't know the script that well to know if there are planned situations in which it may print to standard out but not create a log file. I just don't see how a situation like that could occur when copy-pasting the command into the terminal works like a dream.

Comment: Some programs behave differently when they're not talking to a terminal, so `pdflatex` might not print anything to the standard output when it isn't talking to a terminal.